# If God created us with the capacity of free will. I choose to leave this life and be up there and watch the world beside him, why is it not happening?

Tags: free-will

If God created us with the capacity to love and thereby giving us the ability of free will, the ability too choose. He has given us the choise to be a decent human beings but also the choise to commit sin, which he does not like and that is understandabe but he allows it. With my ability to choose why can I not choose to leave this place, my body, this life, and simply sit beside him and watch the world with him?

Comment: Not having the ability to realise any choice you can imagine (like having the ability to fly) doesn't mean the choices you can make aren't real.

Comment: So God allows us to behave the way we want, the actions we commit are real but he does not allow us to realise any choise we have. It's like we have free will but at the same time we do not. God put the rule that you can only leave this place if you are dead. If you are dead God decided that you are unconcious and that you are too await resurrection.

Comment: @MauricioRamirezZavala God is God. He makes the rules for our benefit. Your life is important and there is a big mission for you to fulfill, but you decide whether you take the mission, or do what you want in this life. This life is borrowed. You did not work to create your life, God lent it to you. If you do nothing with it and waste it, as many do, you will be judged according to your work. See the parable of the talents.

Comment: @MauricioRamirezZavala I'm afraid your cavalier attitude toward life and free will is **not** how God our creator intended us to use, just like a parent giving freedom to a teenager.  God loves you and wants you to flourish.  Free will is a gift with responsibility attached.  Free will properly exercised will elevate you to amazing communion with God, not intended to do nothing.  Also remember God is King.  Do you think you can just sit next to Queen Elizabeth without invitation and worthiness?

Answer (score 1):

This is from an SDA perspective.

That depends on what your belief is of what happens after death. Based on the Bible, when you die, you are unconcious and await the resurrection.

There is Biblical support that supports the idea of death sleep:
The dead do not know anything:

> For the living know that they will die; But the dead know nothing, And
>   they have no more reward, For the memory of them is forgotten.
>
> Ecclesiastes 9:5

The dead cannot do anything:

> Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with all your might; for there
>   is no activity or planning or knowledge or wisdom in Sheol where you
>   are going.
>
> Ecclesiastes 9:10

The dead cannot praise God, or hope in His faithfulness:

> For the dead cannot praise you; they cannot raise their voices in
>   praise. Those who go down to the grave can no longer hope in your
>   faithfulness.
>
> Isaiah 38:18

There is no mention of God by the dead:

> For there is no mention of You in death; In Sheol who will give You
>   thanks?
>
> Psalms 6:5

Jesus mentions that Lazarus, who was at the time dead, was simply sleeping:

> 11 These things He said, and after that He said to them, “Our friend
>   Lazarus sleeps, but I go that I may wake him up.”
>
> 12 Then His disciples said, “Lord, if he sleeps he will get well.” 13
>   However, Jesus spoke of his death, but they thought that He was
>   speaking about taking rest in sleep.
>
> 14 Then Jesus said to them plainly, “Lazarus is dead. 15 And I am glad
>   for your sakes that I was not there, that you may believe.
>   Nevertheless let us go to him.”
>
> John 11:11-15

Paul says that those who sleep, or died in Christ, simply wait for His return and their resurrection.

> 13 But I do not want you to be ignorant, brethren, concerning those
>   who have fallen asleep, lest you sorrow as others who have no hope. 14
>   For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so God will
>   bring with Him those who sleep in Jesus.[b]
>
> 15 For this we say to you by the word of the Lord, that we who are
>   alive and remain until the coming of the Lord will by no means precede
>   those who are asleep. 16 For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven
>   with a shout, with the voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of
>   God. And the dead in Christ will rise first. 17 Then we who are alive
>   and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet
>   the Lord in the air. And thus we shall always be with the Lord. 18
>   Therefore comfort one another with these words.
>
> 1 Thessalonians 4:13-18

From this perspective, you don't watch the world, as mainstream Christianity would have you believe. It is unbiblical and was adopted from Greek Philosophy.

Comment: While many take exception to the doctrine of soul sleep, myself included, I appreciate the depth of this answer, particularly that it refutes the ideas in the question *without* addressing the nature of freewill, and much of your reasoning can be adapted without affirming soul sleep.